# Is there any way to Tether through wifi?

Tags: tethering

I have a desktop without a wifi card. Can I tether my computer to the phone but the data should go through wifi rather than the plan?

I want  PC - USB -> Android phone - Wi-Fi -> internet

Comment: I asked my neighbor if I can share his internet and he said it's fine.

Comment: ^ So the problem is solved right?

Comment: Can we just clarify this? It sounds like you want PC - USB -> Android phone - Wi-Fi -> internet. If this is correct, please [edit] your question to make it clear for other visitors who might be able to help.

Comment: I think he wants to use the Android device in lieu of a wifi card for the PC, operating the phone as something akin to a wifi bridge.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called Easy Tether [(XDA questions about doing it)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1276723) which can do that. You basically just set up USB tethering and disable the "use LTE" or "use 3G" settings, to force it to fall-back to wifi. Personally it seems a bit silly to do that, when a $10 wifi adapter that plugs into the PC with USB would likely work better.. but yes, you can in theory do it.